# Assembly Instruction unknown

Tags: assembly

Hopefully you can help me on this. I have some asm code with an unfamiliar instruction, I have searched but can't find an example with this syntax. Heres the instruction

```
ld 16,r3,r5
```

and

```
ld -1,*+ar5,r2    ; PRE-GAIN: -1 to reverse SD doubling
```

Now i know its loading r3 into r5 as r5 is used for the rest of the block, but what is the first argument for?
I thought it might be a multiply, but i have another other instructions where the first argument is a 0.

I must point out that the architecture is a **proprietary 32-bit fixed point audio dsp**, and it is very old code, so I can no longer contact the company who made the chip.

Please help.

More code

```
calc:  
  ld 16,r3,r5
  ldi #coef_update_2,paer
  rptb #Son_F_Loop
    ld 0,*+ar4,r2
    ld 0,*+ar5,r4
    sub r4,r2
    mpy r5,r2,r0
coef_update_2:
    add r0,r4
    st 0,r4,*+ar6
  jmp #STEPING_volume,u,0
```

Comment: Which CPU architecture is that?

Comment: There aren't only one architecture in the world, you know?

Comment: Yes @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc. I am aware that asm can vary between architecture. Im asking an open question to anyone who may have seen such an instruction. If you do not know the answer do not reply, it is only wasting both our time.

Comment: The architecture is proprietary, and it is very old code, so I can no longer contact the company who made the chip.

Comment: Can you disclose the manufacturer name and/or the name of the chip?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot, NDA :/ 
I have searched far and wide for any reference to them, their chip, or this instruction to no avail.

Comment: Where did you found that? Doesn't it specify what architecture that instruction is, or anything related to that?

Comment: All I can say on its architecture is it is 1 of 2, 32-bit fixed point embedded audio dsp cores, there is not a lot else I can say. 
I am only asking if anyone has seen an instruction 
    ld a,b,c

Comment: My initial guess would be that the immediate value would be an offset - i.e. an add, not a multiply. Beyond that I think more context would be necessary. If not a description of the processor, at least more code...

Comment: I have added more code to the post

Comment: hint: try to search for specs about the assembly languages of more modern DSP based on such old DSP... maybe the newest DSPs share a lot of opcodes with the oldest one. Much like the x86 family...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across something similar before. Not sure if the architecture is the same, but i'm gonna guess that:

`"LD sft, Rx, Ry"` where `(Rx << sft) -> Ry`. A negative number for `sft` changes the shift to `>>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code then it's easy to find out. With a google search I found lots of relevant result. It may be of the [TMS320](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments_TMS320) line of chip although I don't know what architecture ld and ldi belongs to. I've looked at the manuals but cannot found ldi although I can see many other registers and instructions

In the code above AR4, AR5 are the low parts or XAR4, XAR5 and mpy is a multiply instruction, rather strange naming. RPTB is "Repeat Block of Instructions Unconditionally"

http://lina.faculty.asu.edu/realdsp/Manuals/C55xInstructionSet.pdf

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/TMS320C3x_002fC4x-Options.html

http://www.elec.canterbury.ac.nz/c4x/doc/c4x-tools.html

http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/~johnr/papers/pdf/c30course.pdf

Some books on google about this:

[Real-Time Digital Signal Processing - Implementations, Applications and Experiments With the TMS320C55X](http://books.google.com/books?id=70scPIwK7cUC&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=rptb+mpy+instruction&source=bl&ots=4arljyBJAV&sig=zLZSW24wmqkvclsv51YDlUBWopc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=q10gU7_0BojhyQHUzoHgCQ&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=rptb%20mpy%20instruction&f=false)

[Real-Time Digital Signal Processing: Fundamentals, Implementations and Applications](http://books.google.com/books?id=QQlwAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA512&lpg=PA512&dq=rptb+mpy+instruction&source=bl&ots=cETXx9tnFZ&sig=1asYL5k0_PNIkmzhpmjfszY5T94&hl=en&sa=X&ei=q10gU7_0BojhyQHUzoHgCQ&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=rptb%20mpy%20instruction&f=false)

More specifics on TI's document http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ug/sprueo2a/sprueo2a.pdf

Edit:

I found many ldi examples but all of them have 2 operands. The only case where there are 3 is when one of them is in brackets `()`

```
ldi @_y,ar0
ldi 0,ar2
ldi 4,ir0
ldi ar2,ir1
ldi *+ar0(ir1),r7
ldi *ar2++(ir0)b,r6
```

http://www.innovative-dsp.com/support/appnotes/dnp3.pdf